# Delphi Firedac SQL Server: no error raised when update fails because record is locked

Tags: sql-server, delphi, error-handling, locking, firedac

I'm currently working on a project to migrate code base from using Advantage Database Server to SQL Server.

I'm using Firedac of XE8 linked to a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express.

I have a small test project. There's a TDBGrid showing the content of a table (the query lock mode is Pessimistic, lockpoint immediate).

I have another `TQuery` with a SQL command like this:

```
update myTable 
set firstName = 'John'
where id = 1
```

What I do :

1. I put the first row in `Edit` mode (by writing something in the cell)
2. When I press a button, it runs `executeSQL` on the `Update` query
3. Nothing happens -- the update query does not go through

That's fine ... but I was expecting an error message telling me the `UPDATE` didn't go trough...

How can I get the same behavior but with an error message triggered ?

Comment: Did you restart your app and you find that the name is not john?

Comment: What happens when you attempt the same update by executing it in MS Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: Sami: Exactly.  The name is not John.

Comment: MartynA : I execute the UPDATE when row is in Edit mode. A timeCursor appears before 'Executing query...' in Management Studio.  When I exit from Edit mode : the green checkMark and message 'Query executed successfully' appears in Management Studio. In my app, the field was updated from the UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essential connection settings to work with row locks :

```
TFDConnection.UpdateOptions.Lockmode := lmPessimistic;

TFDConnection.UpdateOptions.LockPoint := lmImmediate;

TFDConnection.UpdateOptions.LockWait := False;
```

Behaviour described is SQL Server waiting for the lock to be removed to finish commiting the UPDATE.  By setting your FireDACconnection to 'no wait' it's going to raise an exception as soon as you attempt to do something on the row you've locked by putting the dataset in Edit. Then you can catch this exception to do what you want.